# Having trouble adding event clicks to options in Select2 dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having an issue with the Select2 dropdown which is preventing me from adding links to external sites to options inside the dropdown.

I've been following several guides, however most are out of date as apparently Select2's events have been updated.

I've been trying to implement the following JS/JQ, however I'm not sure if I'm placing it in the right position, or even if its correct.

The purpose of this is to add link buttons to the end of each option/element which would take the user to an external site. I would prefer if the whole focus/hover area was a linked button, however it appears this is not possible with Select2?

```
function format(state) {
if (!state.id) return state.text; // optgroup
return state.text + " <i class='info'>link</i>";
}

var select2 = $("#select").select2({
formatResult: format,
formatSelection: format,
escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; }
}).data('select2');

select2.onSelect = (function(fn) {
return function(data, options) {
    var target;

    if (options != null) {
        target = $(options.target);
    }

    if (target && target.hasClass('info')) {
        alert('click!');
    } else {
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
})(select2.onSelect);
```

Unfortunately it either fails to work and/or all other script is ignored.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Bare in mind I'm a bit amateur with JS.

https://jsfiddle.net/dowenrockit/y3yoh1ao/

Comment: Can you post jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry this is a really poor jsfiddle but wanted to try and show most of the code in case there was an anomaly somewhere. It's all a little messy.https://jsfiddle.net/dowenrockit/y3yoh1ao/

Comment: Still struggling with this at the moment! Have tried moving any updated script to main.js but still no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, im not quite sure what your trying to accomplish, and that jsfiddle is insane.

Heres an updated one which includes jQuery and Select2, as well as some of your css. I removed most of the code that is not needed. As well as all your javascript.

https://jsfiddle.net/y3yoh1ao/4/

This fiddle also includes the basic usage of the select element, which allows a user to select a element, and does something with it programatically.

If you want the user to go to a website whenever the user clicks on the element, all you have to do is either set the links as the values of the option and then to a `window.location.href = value`. which sends the user to that page.

ex. `window.location.href = "http://google.com"`

Or you can interpret the value of the option, and get the link from an array or something.

`var myLinks["CA"] = "http://facebook.com"
window.location.href = myLinks[value];`

This way, as far as i interpret your question, the entire  works as a button.

Comment: I'm going to just delete this request as it's just too messy to try and resolve! I've figured out a method in the mean time. So will leave this here for now. Thanks for your help though!